# Force mobile view to not resize content

Tags: html, ipad, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I recently sliced a PSD for a super low budget client and I am having a weird issue. When I look at the website on an Ipad, it is resizing a background image and making it smaller than everything else. I have noticed that mobile devices resize content so that it fits on the small screen when zoomed in, so I'm assumimg that is what's happening here, and that because everything in the section that is being resized has an absolute position, nothing else is resizing with the parent. My question is, how do i force that section tag with the background image to not resize and to stay the same.

The webpage is www.thewildernesswalk.com/new-home.html. I have tried most browsers with no problem. It seems like the only problem is on my ipad.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari supports background size. You can force the size by adding:

`background-size: 100%;`

to your `.paths` class.

Once you add that, it should work...

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jack. I thought I had done that already but maybe not. As soon as I get close to an ipad i'll test it and if it works i'll definitely give you the credit. Thanks again.